# pandas pivot table does not add but concatenates the values

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I am trying to make a pivot table using pandas

```
ns = pd.read_csv('latest_sg.csv')
sfdc = pd.read_csv('report1.csv')
```

Matching the column to lookup

```
ns.rename(columns={'accountid':'Account ID'},inplace = True)
```

A vlookup

```
lookup = pd.merge(ns,sfdc[['Account ID','Account Status']],on=['Account ID'],how='left')
lookup = lookup.dropna(axis=0, subset=['Account Status'])
```

The pivot table

```
pivot = lookup.pivot_table(index='Account ID',values='gb',aggfunc='sum',fill_value=0)
```

The problem is that with `print(pivot)`, the output does not return the sum of the column 'gb' values but concatenates the values.

Ex. if an Account ID say 'qwer' has 3 rows with values in 'gb' as 3,4 and 5 the output should be

```
qwer               12
```

but the output is

```
qwer               345
```

Please help!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. My guess is that the values are strings, not ints.

Comment: [don't link to a csv we don't have access to...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159305/1422451)

Answer (score 1):

Your column is most likely an object and an integer, the strings being concatenated is the expected behaviour, use

```
df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col])
```

and `print(df.dtypes)` to check your column datatypes.

if you need to ignore strings in your numerical column you can add a further argument to cast non numeric values into nan

```
pd.to_numeric(df[col], errors='coerce')
```

to further illustrate this

```
1 + 1 
>> 2
'1' + '1'
>> '11'
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for the help, you are a savior!

Comment: @Kimberly_Jennifer no problem, read the links above in the comments and accept this answer if it answered your question (green tick under the arrows) best of luck